# Import external js with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Say I have 2 js files in `resources/assets/js`, one is `app.js` & the other is `ext_app.js`

There is a function in `ext_app.js` as below:

```
function testFunction() {
    // function code
}
```

And in `app.js`:

```
require('./bootstrap');
require('./ext_app.js');

const app = new Vue({
    // other stuff

    mounted: function() {
        // Call my test function from ext_app.js
        testFunction();
    }
});
```

Ran `npm run dev` & look into `public/js/app.js`, the `ext_app.js` code is there, pretty good anyway. But, the app returns the following error when run on Chrome:

```
[Vue warn]: Error in mounted hook: "ReferenceError: testFunction is not defined"
```

What have I miss?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to export the testFunction before you can require it.

```
module.exports = function testFunction() {
   // function code
}
```