# Import external javascript file and use functions globally in vue app

Tags: javascript, vue.js, import

I'm using Vue.js (cli 3) to build a mock webbshop to practice. I got a javascript file with all the functions for buttons, the basket and the checkout.

Instead of copying all the code into my own vue app. **How can I import the Javascript file without getting errors?**

#### What I've tried:

Adding import into the main.js file in my Vue App.*(I read through this explanation but I honestly don't understand fully what's happening)*

```
import webbshop from '@/assets/lib/js/webbshop.js';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$webbshop', { value: webbshop });
```

found here:
https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/04/22/vue-js-libraries-plugins/

Putting a `console.log("Test from my webbshop.js")` in the beginning. **<- works**

**I get this error in Chrome:**

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
    at showBasket (webshop.js?709d:146)
```

I also get 21 errors in terminal of VS Code when saving the document.
eg.

```
error: 'i' is already defined (no-redeclare) at src/assets/lib/js/webbshop.js:105:18:
  103 | 
  104 |         // Loopa genom varor
> 105 |         for (var i = 0; i < basketItems.length; i++) {
      |                  ^
  106 |             // Räkna ut kostnad och lägg till summa
  107 |             var itemCost = parseInt(basketItems[i].artCost);
  108 |
```

or

```
error: 'addToBasket' is defined but never used (no-unused-vars) at src/assets/lib/js/webbshop.js:31:10:
  29 | 
  30 | /* Lägg till i varukorg */
> 31 | function addToBasket(el, id, name, cost, image, notify = false) {
     |          ^
  32 | 
  33 |     // Börja med en vara
  34 |     numOfItems = 1;
```

When I create a button with `onclick="addToBasket([some parameters])"` it throws error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: addToBasket is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick ((index):16)
```

#### I also tried:

At the very end of main.js just to keep working and not getting stuck until I get an answer.

```
function loadjsfile(filename){
        var fileref=document.createElement('script')
        fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript")
        fileref.setAttribute("src", filename)
}
 
loadjsfile("@/assets/lib/js/webbshop.js")
```

It doesn't load the file at all. But no errors.

### From main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import webbshop from '@/assets/lib/js/webbshop.js';
Object.defineProperty(Vue.prototype, '$webbshop', { value: webbshop });

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

It doesn't have to be scalable or in other means the best solution. I just want a simple way how to import functions from my other file and have them **globally accessible in each component of my Vue project.**

I read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51556338/import-external-js-with-vue)
and I can't imagine I have to put *module.exports* on from of each function in my external file. Or do I?

> You need to export the testFunction before you can require it.
>
> ```
> module.exports = function testFunction() {
>   // function code
> }
> ```

#### Expectations:

I want to access all the functions in the external js file to use in other component.vue files throughout my app.

#### Actual results:

The browser reads the external js file but the functions don't work.

Comment: It looks like some of these errors are reported by eslint (e.g. `i is already defined`). You should fix them.

Answer (score 4):

to add function(s) globally to `vue` you need to extended `vue` and write as `plugin`
it is pretty easy

[link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html)

do it as the fallow:
create file `plugin.js`

```
import webbshop from '@/assets/lib/js/webbshop.js';

// MyPlugin its just a name change to whatever meet you needs.
MyPlugin.install = function (Vue, options) {
  Vue.myGlobalMethod = function () {
    webshop.dothis();
  };

  Vue.mySecondGlobalMethod = function (a,b,c) {
    webshop.dothis(a,b,c);
  };
...
}
```

now import it to the main Vue file.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import plugin from './plugin'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

Vue.use(plugin)

new Vue({
  router,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

after that vue attach your custom methods to all vue instances.
and you can access it anywhere by simply refer it to a vue inner function.
in markup:

```
<h1 v-text="mySecondGlobalMethod(1,2,3)"></h1>
```

in javascript:

```
 const b = this.myGlobalMethod();
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly I need to import my webbshop.js file into a plugin and there declare all the functions as methods using:
```
  Vue.myGlobalMethod = function () {
    webshop.dothis();
  };
```
So I'm grabbing all the functions and calling them something new (or same) but as a method to Vue.{newGlobalMethod}. And to invoke it I just as normal in markup?

Such as `<button onclick="myGlobalMethod()">Buy</button>?

Comment: I've tried all of this now a few times. Even completely replacing my own webshop.js file with a dummy test.js file only containing `function myFunction(){console.log('Test')} ` No of it worked and it actually crashed my app. I copied and pasted all the code that you suggested and also tried from Vuejs.org

Comment: Does not work. MyPlugin is not defined in the plugin.js file, so how can you add a "install" function to it?